# How can I split install.wim from Windows installation ISO on OSX?

Tags: bootcamp, windows, fat32

I want to make a bootable Windows installation USB on OSX. However, I run into the problem with isntall.wim file that doesn't fit into FAT32 4GB file limit.

All google results about this problem ([like this article](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/manufacture/desktop/split-a-windows-image--wim--file-to-span-across-multiple-dvds)) describe the solutions that I can use on a Windows system. How can I split the install.wim file if I only have a working OS X system? Is there anything similar to `Dism /Split-Image` console tool that I can use?